# How to create an array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

Trying to write my first python program. In a working sample program (script), some array of data is defined like this:

```
x_data = np.random.rand(100).astype(np.float32)
```

And when I subsequently type "x_data" in a Python console, it returns

```
    >>> x_data
        array([ 0.16771448,  0.55470788,  0.36438608, ...,  0.21685787,
        0.14241569,  0.20485006], dtype=float32)
```

and the script works.

Now I want to use my own data sets instead.  I'm trying a statement like this

```
my_data = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

and replace use of x_data with my_data, but then the program doesn't work.  I notice that when I type "my_data" in the Python console, it returns

```
>>> my_data
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

which is missing the parts that say "array" and "dtype=float32".  I'm guessing that difference is related to the problem.

**How can I declare a dataset my_data that would be treated like x_data so I can feed my own data into the program?**

I think it's irrelevant, but here's the full sample script I started from (which works):

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# Create 100 phony x, y data points in NumPy, y = x * 0.1 + 0.3
x_data = np.random.rand(100).astype(np.float32)
y_data = x_data * 0.1 + 0.3

# Try to find values for W and b that compute y_data = W * x_data + b
# (We know that W should be 0.1 and b 0.3, but TensorFlow will
# figure that out for us.)
W = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([1], -1.0, 1.0))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))
y = W * x_data + b

# Minimize the mean squared errors.
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y - y_data))
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5)
train = optimizer.minimize(loss)

# Before starting, initialize the variables.  We will 'run' this first.
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

# Launch the graph.
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

# Fit the line.
for step in range(201):
    sess.run(train)
    if step % 20 == 0:
        print(step, sess.run(W), sess.run(b))

# Learns best fit is W: [0.1], b: [0.3]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you're coming from Matlab?

Python square-bracket notation doesn't give you any type of `array` by default: it gives you a simpler object of the built-in type `list`.  `numpy`, the ubiquitous **third-party** package, is what you want to use for arrays. Clearly you already have it available.

The second line below converts your variable from a `list` to a `numpy` array with the same data type as your other array `x_data`:

```
my_data = [1,2,3,4,5]
my_data = np.array(my_data, dtype=np.float32)
```

Comment: I've always avoided Matlab and Python.  I grew up on C++.  Thanks for the quick help!

Answer (score 1):

numpy will construct an array from a list if you just use `np.array`:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Note that you can specify the datatype as well:

```
arr_int32 = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=np.int32)
arr_float = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=np.float64)
```

Also note that there are times when you might be working with an object that might be a list or it might be a numpy array.  `np.array` will copy an array if you pass that in as input.  That is sometimes not desireable for performance reasons.  If you find yourself in that situation, you can use `np.asarray` which will convert non-arrays into arrays but it'll return arrays untouched.